# Firefox no longer works after update

Tags: 12.04, firefox

After updating firefox in Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, yesterday, firefox no longer starts:
That is, I can ask

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 39.0.3
```

but if I call it without arguments, it exits (after many syscalls according to strace) which is rather large:

```
$ rm -fr .mozilla
$ strace firefox 2> firefox.strace
$ wc firefox.strace 
 11481  95492 958346 firefox.strace
```

I also moved `.mozilla` away, but to no avail.

As suggested by @clearkimura, here is the result of running the profile manager:[image: The ugly truth]

How can I get it working again?

Comment: @cleakimura: No error messages - only strace messages. Hard to decipher, but I will try...

Comment: Please see above!

Comment: @clearkimura: So I deinstalled and reinstalled ff. Now it works but it has ruined all my bookmarks. Well, that's what Ubuntu is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer includes steps taken in comments above, with additional steps to backup bookmarks in Firefox and purge and reinstall the package.

### Troubleshooting steps

1. In Terminal, type `firefox -P -no-remote` and hit **Return** or **Enter** key.

   If successful, this will prompt you with a list of Firefox user profiles. If it did, try to create a new profile and run Firefox using that.
2. If step 1 failed, confirm that Firefox is really not running by using `strace firefox` command* in Terminal.

   If Firefox exits by itself, the last several lines contains only `exit_group(0)`.

   In contrast, Firefox that exits normally upon user action (by clicking on **Close** `x` button or using **Alt+F4** combination key) will contain `close(8)` `close(7)` `exit_group(0)` in the last three lines of *above command.
3. Optionally, backup your bookmarks by copying the `bookmarkbackups` directory that is found under `./mozilla/firefox/PROFILEDIR` to somewhere for later use.

   In which, `PROFILEDIR` may look something like `XXXXXXXX.default` for the profile that Firefox has created by default.
4. Remove the `.mozilla` directory which is found under the **Home** directory of current user.

   > $ rm -rf ~/.mozilla
5. Purge the package (this is preferred than `apt-get remove` command, in case the package that has been downloaded earlier is corrupted when upgrading Ubuntu)

   > $ sudo apt-get purge firefox
6. Install the package that is downloaded new

   > $ sudo apt-get install firefox
7. Finally, run Firefox as usual.

### Restore bookmarks in Firefox

If you have done step 3, you can now restore your bookmark from the freshly installed Firefox. You will be using one of the files inside the `bookmarkbackups` directory.

- In Firefox, open the bookmark manager a.k.a **Library** (either by **Alt+B** > **Show All Bookmarks** or using **Ctrl+Shift+O** key combination will do).
- In **Library**, click on **Import and Backup** button and select **Restore** > **Choose File...**.
- Navigate to the `bookmarkbackups` directory you had copied earlier.
- Select the latest `*.json*` file found inside the directory and click **OK**.

It will take a few moment, depending on your bookmark file size. The restored bookmark is found under **Unsorted bookmarks** > **YYYYMMDD**.

Whereby, **YYYYMMDD** is part of the filename of `*.json*` file you had selected earlier and it is also the date the bookmark backup that has been created in your older install of Firefox.

### Compatibility notes

The troubleshooting steps should be applicable to recent Firefox releases on any Ubuntu releases, not just 12.04. I have decided to provide generic answer, since other earlier questions and answers didn't have this kind of advice.

Comment: What about saved passwords?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/478187). But unlike bookmarks, there is no direct way to restore the passwords in Firefox (You can check the **Preferences** > **Security** by yourself). Unless, you resort to install Add-Ons for that. I'd suggest to use [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) that backs up almost everything in Firefox instead. Obviously, you should do this *before* upgrading Ubuntu. When Firefox or whatever breaks later, there's limited options to save anything.

Comment: I did not explicitly upgrade to a new version, I did just the suggested updates from the Update Manager. In any case, that teaches me a lesson about upgrades.