# I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Firefox is giving me all kinds of problems, how do I reinstall it?

Tags: apt, 18.04, firefox

In the past 3 to 4 months Firefox has decided to start randomly freezing for minutes, starting up **slowly**.

I think my bet is to reinstall it, how would I do it?

*Even though it's not essential, I would love to be able to keep the passwords stored in Gnome Keyring.* I couldn't care less about my extensions.

Is `sudo apt remove firefox` and `sudo apt install firefox` enough?

Comment: perhaps `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen do you think this would let me keep my passwords? It wouldn't be that bad if I lost them, but I would prefer keeping them.

Comment: My suggestion is to copy the default session file and add it back after reinstall not sure what gets nuked but I suspect it does

Comment: Copy the `*.default` folder and `profile.ini` file

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I just did it, Firefox kept the passwords (and the extensions) but the problem is still there

Comment: According to the top answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/403676/how-do-i-export-saved-passwords-from-my-firefox-password-manager, the passwords are stored in the file `logins.json` in your profile folder, which currently is of the form `~/.mozilla/firefox/[some_string].default/`.

Comment: then perhaps memory usage is the problem

Comment: An extension can also cause problems. Try to tart FF with disabled extensions.

Comment: I am having a similar problem where FF freezes my desktop for a minute or so when first started after boot. I have not been able to diagnose the problem at all.