# Simple Export Firefox Quantum Logins and Passwords

Tags: firefox

[Firefox is not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165216/545291) and I would like to backup my L&P data before taking any corrective action.  I found an old and convoluted [procedure to export](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403676/how-do-i-export-saved-passwords-from-my-firefox-password-manager).  Is there a simple method from the UI (preferable) or command line to export L&P in plain text?

Comment: You may find this resource helpful: https://github.com/kspearrin/ff-password-exporter. Since v57 existing password export additions to FF no longer work

Comment: The old and convoluted [procedure to export](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403676/how-do-i-export-saved-passwords-from-my-firefox-password-manager) still works, I just tested the answer by [jignesh-gohel](https://askubuntu.com/users/428475/jignesh-gohel) which worked perfectly.

Comment: @mook765  Thanks for the data point.  Please consider updating your comment to reflect version of FF / Ubuntu

Comment: @gatorback I used the current version 68.0.1 for the test.

Answer (score 3):

You can backup bookmarks, passwords and everything (your profile) up by going to **`~/.mozilla/firefox`**(it is a hidden folder in your `home` folder).  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show/toggle the hidden files in `nautilus` file manager.

You'll find many files and folders, the ones you need to back-up/export are those I selected (Make sure you exit from Firefox browser to be able to copy the files):

[image]

After copying them to a safe place, you can uninstall Firefox then install it again (or do whatever you want), then move the files you backed-up to `~/.mozilla/firefox` again. After that open Firefox, and you'll find everything safe as you let it before re-installing Firefox.

**Source:**  For more details or to restore your profile to a different location, please visit [mozilla support website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles)